# Best way to create SVG from database? (Using PHP)

Tags: php, svg

I've got a SQL database that keeps track of which services a client has.  I need to create an image using SVG that only displays the services that the client has.  The database stores the services in the format `1,2,3,6,7,9`.  Here's what I have:

```
 <?php
    header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
    $db = new PDO(**[redacted]**);
    $grabServices = $db->prepare("SELECT services FROM *** where name= :name");
    $grabServices->execute(array(":name" => "test" ));
    $services = $grabServices->fetchAll();
    $services = explode(",", $services[0][services]);
    var_dump($services);
?>

//snip...

<?php if(in_array(1, $services)){?>
    <line x1="820" y1="120" x2 ="790" y2="180" class="SaaS"/>
<?php }?>
<?php if(in_array(2, $services)){?>
    <line x1="905" y1="180" x2 ="700" y2="370" class="PM"/>
<?php }?>
//etc, etc,
```

This seems incredibly tedious to me.  The only other way I can think to do this would have all the SVG elements created in a PHP array, but that seems even more wasteful.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$formats = array(
    '1' => array(
        'x1' => 820,
        'y1' => 120
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'x1' => 905,
        'y1' => 180
    )
);
?>

<?php foreach( $formats as $key => $format ) : ?>
    <?php if ( in_array( (int) $key, $services ) ) : ?>
        <line x1="<?php print $format['x1']; ?>" y1="<?php print $format['y1']; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I didn't do it for every field, but you get the idea.

This is tedious to write the array. But you *have to* write it somewhere. If there is no logic, the computer can't guess.

I think it's easier to read/write a simple array than all this XML though.